# Is there a name for this exponential analog to modular arithmetic? (octave equivalency)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, music-theory

In music theory, there is a concept called *octave equivalency*: two pitches are said to have the same pitch class if the quotient of their frequencies is a power of 2, i.e. if they are an integer number of octaves apart.

This relation can be generalized to use powers of $n$ other than 2. For example, the [Bohlen-Pierce Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohlen%E2%80%93Pierce_scale) doesn't use octave-equivalency, but what it calls *tritave*-equivalency; pitches are equivalent if the quotient of their frequencies is a power of 3.

It seems to me that this is analagous to modular arithmetic, but exponential rather than multiplicative: two numbers are congruent mod $k$ if their difference is a multiple of $k$. So while the modulo operation and modular congruence can be recursively defined as:

$$
n\bmod{k} = 
\begin{cases}
(n-k)\bmod{k}, & \text{if $n\ge k$} \\
(n+k)\bmod{k}, & \text{if $n<0$} \\
n, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
a\equiv b\pmod{k} \iff a\bmod{k} = b\bmod{k},
$$

octave/tritave/etc.-equivalency (more generally $k$-tave-equivalency) can be recursively defined with:

$$
n \text{ tave } k = 
\begin{cases}
(\frac{n}{k}) \text{ tave } k, & \text{if $n\ge k$} \\
(n\cdot k) \text{ tave } k, & \text{if $n<1$} \\
n, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
a\equiv b\;\;\;\;\text{($k$-tave)} \iff a \text{ tave } k = b \text{ tave } k
$$

Another way of looking at the two concepts:

- $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod $k$ iff the fractional part of $\frac{a}{k}$ equals the fractional part of $\frac{b}{k}$.
- $a$ and $b$ are $k$-tave-equivalent iff the fractional part of $\log_k{a}$ equals the fractional part of $\log_k{b}$.

Is there a name for the operation I call "tave" above? Is this a concept that gets use in mathematics outside music theory?

Comment: You are looking at the quotient group $G/H$ where $G$ is the group of positive real numbers under multiplication and $H$ is the subgroup generated by $2$.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with group theory; I'm assuming $H$ is the subgroup generated by $k$ in general, with $k=2$ in the case of the octave, yes?

Comment: Indeed${}{}{}$.

Comment: Then, by analogy, is modular arithmetic the difference group $G-H$ where $G$ is the group of positive reals under addition and $H$ is the subgroup generated by $k$?